# mySQL WooCommerce - Table of Products, Categories, Price and Quantity Sole

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build the following mySQL table for a quick sales report:

```
ID     Category     Product     Category_ID     Price     Quantity
101    CAT-A        ITEM-A      1001            5         3
102    CAT-C        ITEM-F      1003            12        2
103    CAT-B        ITEM-S      1002            15        6
```

However I'm currently at:

```
ID     Category     Product     Category_ID     Price     Quantity
101    NULL         ITEM-A      NULL            5         NULL
102    NULL         ITEM-F      NULL            12        NULL
103    NULL         ITEM-S      NULL            15        NULL
```

My query looks sort of OK, I've broken down all the sections individually, but I don't think I'm using the right functions for Quantity and Category.

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    t.name AS 'Category',
    p.post_title AS 'Product',
    tt.term_taxonomy_id AS 'Category_ID',
    MAX(CASE WHEN pm1.meta_key = '_price' THEN pm1.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as 'Price',
    SUM(CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_qty'   THEN oim.meta_value ELSE NULL END) as 'Quantity'
FROM wpdc_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_postmeta AS pm1 ON pm1.post_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND tr.object_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON oi.order_item_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id AND oim.meta_key = '_qty'
WHERE
    p.post_type IN('product', 'product_variation') AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_content <> ''
GROUP BY
    t.name,
    p.post_title
```

If I take this part out, the categories show up, but there's too many items:     **`AND tr.object_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id`**

Kind regards,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working, I just needed to create sub-queries for both the category lookups, and counting each product that was sold.

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT
    (SELECT wp_terms.name
        FROM wp_terms
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
        WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID) AS 'Category',

    wp_posts.post_title AS 'Product',

    (SELECT SUM(wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value)
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
        WHERE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_qty'
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_name = wp_posts.post_title) AS 'Quantity',

    MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_price' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS 'Price'

FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id

WHERE
    wp_posts.post_type IN('product', 'product_variation') AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_content <> ''

GROUP BY
    Category, Product
```